# Many to Many table with extra assoaciations/columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm seeking a better idea of how to handle extra associations in many-to-many table.

```
class Notification
  has_many :recipient_notifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :recipient_notifications, source: :recipient, source_type: "User"
end


class RecipientNotification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :notification
  belongs_to :additional_association, optional: true
end
```

It's easy to add new users to notification like this:

```
notification.users << users
```

Then, on a notification.save, the notification will have an association for given users.

But how can I add additional_association to recipient_notification that is not like this:

```
users.each do |user|
   notification.recipient_notification.create(user: user, additional_association: association_object)
end
```

Note: on notification, there is no direct connection to the additional association object, so I can't use a custom query with [Accessing the owner object](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I don't get it?  How do you want to add recipient_notifications?  Why is your suggestion an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom method in the `Notification` model:

```rb
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipient_notifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :recipient_notifications, source: :recipient, source_type: "User"

  # Custom method to add users with an additional association
  def add_users_with_additional_association(users, association_object)
    users.each do |user|
      self.recipient_notifications.create(
        recipient: user, 
        additional_association: association_object
      )
    end
  end
end
```

With this method, adding users with an additional association becomes straightforward:

```rb
notification.add_users_with_additional_association(users, association_object)
```